# C# how to interrupt read() of networkstream in a background thread?

Tags: c#

A background thread is blocked by calling `Read()` on a `NetworkStream`. How can I interrupt it in UI thread to make the `Read()` call return or throw an Exception ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use ReadAsync and provide a cancellation token.

Then using the cancellation token you can interrupt the read whenever you want.

Comment: To use the *Async() functions, all callers (from bottom to top) must change to async/await. My code is in a callback of a third party lib, so I cannot use the async/await pattern.

Comment: @Zach you can wrap the entire async-stuff into an `Task.Run`-call, which essentially creates a threadpool-thread and then is usable in a sync context.